# Android testing, visualize touching events

Tags: android, testing, touch, visualization, drag

I would like to write an automated test, which visualizes the touch and drag events (those were sent by the test app) with a circular marker. Is there any way to do it using the original Android testing framework? What about robotium? Please provide some source code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch `Dev Tools` application, in `Development Settings` set **Pointer Location**.
Then, you will be able to see where your touches go by a blue cross drawn on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but unfortunately, it is claimed to work on emulators only: "The Dev Tool App is meant to be used only on the dev builds of the platform, such as the emulator" ([Issue 6412](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6412)). I also couldn't get to "Development Settings" without a crash, and the emulators are way too slow (at least, on my PC with WinXP on board).